# Why am I getting an error on one copy of the code but not others,

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron

Ok, so I am making an Electron app and I have this code in my main.js file:

```
ipcMain.handle('getPath', async () => {
  // Dialog options.
  const options = {
      properties: ["openFile"],
      filters: [
          {
              name: "DSC Projects",
              extensions: ["dsc"],
          }
      ]
  }

  // When available, return the modified path back to the render thread via IPC
  const result = await openDialog(win, options);
  if (result.canceled === true) { return; }
  // Modify and return the path
  let filePath = result.filePaths[0];
  return filePath;
})

ipcMain.handle('getTheFile', async () => {
  // Dialog options.
  const options = {
      properties: ["openFile"],
      filters: [
          {
              name: "DSC Projects",
              extensions: ["dsc"],
          }
      ]
  }

  // When available, return the modified path back to the render thread via IPC
  const result = await openDialog(win, options);
  if (result.canceled === true) { return; }
  // Modify and return the path
  let filePath = result.filePaths[0];
  return filePath;
})

// Create an open dialog
function openDialog(parentWindow, options) {
  return dialog.showOpenDialog(parentWindow, options)
      .then((result) => { if (result) { return result; } })
      .catch((error) => { console.error('Show open dialog error: ' + error); });
}
```

If you look at the `ipcMain.handle('getPath')` and `ipcMain.handle('getTheFile')` functions, the code inside them is the same. And so I try to run the `getPath` on with this,

```
window.ipcRender.invoke("getPath").then((path:any)=>{
    console.log(path)
})
```

and that works, everything does what it is supposed to do. However if I change it from `getPath` to `getTheFile`, I get this error instead,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
    at Proxy.hello (Home.vue:22:41)
    at _createVNode.onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (Home.vue:11:48)
    at runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:358:60
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:157:22)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:166:21)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:176:21)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:345:9)
```

Note: I am connecting to my Vue app through Electron so I don't know if that is the problem. I don't suspect it is because Electron is running the function when it has the name of `getPath`.

So really, I am stuck, I've tried changing the name of `getTheFile` to `ss` to see if it was just the name `getTheFile`, however I got the same error. But its weird because when I change `getTheFile` to `getPath` and change getPath to something else, the new `getPath` works and the one that I renamed which used to be `getPath` now doesn't. And it has nothing to do with `getPath` interfering with `getTheFile` because I tried removing `getPath` altogether yet it still didn't allow `getTheFile` to work. So I am stuck.

Comment: Why do you need two identical "functions"?

Comment: I copied it from another project I was working on. However, I don't want the function to be called "getPath" instead I want it to be called "openProject". But if I can't change the name, then how am I suppose to make it called "openProject"? Especially when it wont run when it is not called "getPath"...

Comment: When you have the error is the `getPath` thing in the script? Try removing it

Comment: I have tried as I mentioned above. And that doesn't fix it.

Comment: then i can't helo you since i dont use electron